# migrating plugins developed in eclipse 3.7 to eclipse 4.4.2

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, migration

I have plugins which was developed in eclipse 3.7 and now i want to migrate those plugins to 4.4.2.

But if i try to run run or create a product i am getting below error.

i have 1 feature product and 20 plugins.
I have added those plugins to feature product and from there i am running the product.

Please suggest me who to build a product without any issue.

**Error**

`!SESSION 2015-12-30 15:23:00.081
----------------------------------------------- eclipse.buildId=unknown java.version=1.8.0_66 java.vendor=Oracle Corporation BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US Framework arguments:  -product com.bosch.de.iStar.Branding.iStar Command-line arguments:  -product com.bosch.de.iStar.Branding.iStar -data B:\workspaces\Plug in development/../runtime-iStar.product -dev file:B:/workspaces/Plug in development/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/iStar.product/dev.properties
-os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -consoleLog`

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.runtime 4 0 2015-12-30 15:23:00.627 !MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR !STACK 0 org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.core.runtime [2]   Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: javax.annotation; bundle-version="1.1.0"; visibility:="reexport"; resolution:="optional"   Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: javax.inject; bundle-version="1.0.0"; visibility:="reexport"; resolution:="optional"   Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.jobs; bundle-version="[3.2.0,4.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"

at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)     at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)  at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1562)  at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)  at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)  at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)     at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-12-30 15:23:00.631 !MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.10.0.v20140318-2214.jar was not resolved.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.runtime 2 0 2015-12-30 15:23:00.637 !MESSAGE Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.core.runtime [2]   Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: javax.annotation; bundle-version="1.1.0"; visibility:="reexport"; resolution:="optional"   Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: javax.inject; bundle-version="1.0.0"; visibility:="reexport"; resolution:="optional"   Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.jobs; bundle-version="[3.2.0,4.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-12-30 15:23:00.659 !MESSAGE Application error !STACK 1 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:78)   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)  at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)     at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)

Comment: Exactly how are you running this?

Comment: An improvement on the errors, but the line wrapping and indentation is still all wrong...

Answer (score 0):

(The formatting of the errors in the question is a little messed up and hard to read, if you could correct that great!)

Make sure you have all the dependencies you need. In particular the error says you don't have *javax.annotation*.

This is the part of the error message:

> ENTRY org.eclipse.core.runtime 4 0 2015-12-30 15:23:00.627 !MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR !STACK 0 org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.core.runtime [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjbct.png) Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: javax.annotation; bundle-version="1.1.0"; visibility:="reexport"; resolution:="optional" Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: javax.inject; bundle-version="1.0.0"; visibility:="reexport"; resolution:="optional" Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.jobs; bundle-version="[3.2.0,4.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"

This is what the error message probably looked like on your machine (formatting wise, not detail wise):

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2015-12-30 14:16:58.931
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.ui [12]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui.workbench; bundle-version="[3.105.0,4.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui.workbench; bundle-version="3.107.0.v20150510-1732"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.ui.workbench [151]
         Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.annotation; version="1.0.0"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
```

Therefore, check if *javax.annotation* is included in the launch configuration, or if you are exporting the product before the failure, ensure it is in the dependency chain of your `.product` file.

### Launch Configuration

[image]

### Product File

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Ya i have all the plugins in my feature.but i don't know why it is still showing that error.

Comment: Is there anyother thing dat i should check

Comment: Jonah i am new to this.<br/> I don't know how to post errors

Comment: Format it like code blocks, the important thing that makes it hard to read is the loss of indentation and newlines: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Can you clarify/confirm: It runs and works perfectly in the development environment (i.e. in Eclipse) but the exported version does not work?

Comment: no i am not able to run that.I am trying this from long time.Is there any tool for migration of code.

Comment: Does your project _build_ ok in the IDE (no red markers)? If so, try making sure all plugins are enabled in the launch configuration and proceed from there.

Comment: The new and noteworthy for each release highlights changes to API, but if you are compiling that probably isn't your issued, sample: https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.4/eclipse-news-part3.php